# How to style PropertyTools.WPF ColorPicker?

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

In my app, I'm using custom control - [ColorPicker](https://github.com/PropertyTools/PropertyTools). I want to style it from [Default Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsLg0.png) to [something like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzaYM.png)

But, I don't know where to start with this. Styling it by XAML Setters...

```
<Style TargetType="picker:ColorPicker">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush1}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
...
```

...don't "remove" this metalic, Windows 7 like look (border, click effect, etc.)

How could I style that?